# find an image name and replace it with a different source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension to replace all the occurrences of certain set of image ( I have the image names) and replace it with another image (src)

I need to find all the occurrences of a certain image name in a website and replace the src of the image with a custom image.

I can find the image name in `<img>` tags with the following snippet

```
var key = 'img[src*="' + src + '"]';

var img = $(key);

img.attr('src', 'http://blah.blah/a.png);
```

Problem occurs when the image is set as `background-image` or as a css property. 
Is it possible to scan the `DOM` with `jQuery` (recursively in all the attached style sheets) and replace all the occurrences of the image with the target url? If it is possible, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: are you able to replace image src, but you want to replace it in css background is it?

Comment: You can access stylesheets in Javascript with `document.stylesheets`.

Comment: Correct, So far I am able to replace the images in `<img>` tags, but I need to find all the possible occurences of the image.

Comment: The simplest way would be to  "mark" all the CSS containing the image for example with a certain class name, then just replace the class.

Comment: I think you need to read all elements on page for backgroung-image

Comment: @Teemu I am writing an extension to run on third party websites, So  it is not an option.

Comment: Is there any confirmation that image would be in background for div only?

Comment: @Farhan no, but image can be in anywhere (as per the requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change all inline background images with this:

```
$("[style*=background-image]").css('background-image', function(i, oldimg) {
    return oldimg.indexOf(src) == -1 ? oldimg : 'url(http://blah.blah/a.png)';
});
```

Changing background images in the CSS is trickier.

```
var ss = document.styleSheets;
for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
    var rules = ss[i].cssRules;
    for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
        var rule = rules[i];
        if (rule && rule.type == CSSRule.STYLE_RULE && rule.style.backgroundImage.indexOf(src) != -1) {
            rule.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://blah.blah/a.png)';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` in the `rule.type==...` line. :/

Comment: Sometimes `rules` contains null elements for some reason. I've added a check for that.

Comment: I checked the code, It found 1/4 Images. but It doesn't replace the target image. It remains same.

Comment: @Kaiido The selector only matches elements that have a background image style set. And if it doesn't match the one he's trying to change, it just sets it back to what it was.

Comment: Yep you're right, I was making some tweaks to get the same with the `'*'` selector, my bad, but for all your codes, the value should be `url(http://...)`. So I've got the tweak now : `$('*').css('background-image', function(i, oldimg) {
    if(oldimg!=='none'){
    return oldimg.indexOf(src) == -1 ? oldimg : 'url(newURL)';
    }
});`but that will convert all background-images declared in stylesheets to inline ones..

Comment: @Fawzan As kaiido pointed out, I forgot to wrap the URL with `url(...)`. Try it now.

Comment: Yep, It works for the background images attached targeting  div with an #id. it does't work for the background-images attached targeting the class. In other words, it worked for `div#alpha` and doesn't work for `div.beta` any reason? :/

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that would make a difference.

Comment: Actually, an even better solution would be to  `.replace(src, newUrl)`,  since you can have [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)

Answer (score 3):

I think this could be like this, hope this will help you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("*").each(function(){
        var bgImge = $(this).css('background-image');
        if(bgImge.indexOf('yourImageName') > -1)
        {
          $(this).css('background-image', 'newImage');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: As per my thinking it should work @Fawzan, please give your input too

Comment: sure, I am running tests now. I will update the progress.

Comment: I think bgImge.indexOf('yourImageName') === -1 would be bgImge.indexOf('yourImageName') > -1

Answer (score 1):

You could manually run through each to check it's value:

```
$("*").each(function() {

   var b = $(this).css("background-image") ||  $(this).css("background");

   // check if 'b' has the image name

})
```

Comment: He wants to find all elements that have a background image.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.

Comment: @Barmer is right. I can solve the problem when the image is added as `<img>`.

Comment: @loxxy You're still only changing `<img>` elements, not every element with a background image set. E.g. `<div style="background-image: xxx">`

Comment: lol.. something about the question really didn't fit my brains :D. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on current page, working fine.

```
var src = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=a7723f5f7e59';
$('*').each(function(){
  if( $(this).css('background-image').indexOf(src)!=-1){
   console.log('Found',this);
   $(this).css('background-image','url(http://blah.blah/a.png)');
  }
});
```

Comment: wow, how did you do that? out of all the answers this seems to be the best one. Tested and works fine with the external style sheets.

Comment: Yep, but for dynamically added elements we need to run it again. @Barmar answer look promising